# Magnetic Field Lines in a Circular Solenoid

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electricity, inductance

We know about magnetic field lines in a circular loop and a solenoid. While studying them, I thought about how the magnetic field lines would be in a solenoid made circular by bending, forming something like a torus.

Is this possible? How prominent would the magnetic effect be?

Keen on reading your thoughts and approaches to this!

Comment: You can find numerous diagrams online of what a torus' magnetic field looks like, is there something that you don't understand about them?

Comment: @Triatticus hey there! thanks for your response. It was a mistake on my part for not researching enough before asking the question. I just hopped on to StackExchange and posted the question, when I thought about it. 
So yeah, now that I know that there are resources online, I would definitely research more and learn! Thank you again for your response.
Hope you have a great day and weekend :)

Comment: Sure, you can always go look into it and maybe refine your question later, don't forget to search this site too as you might find derivations or other stuff concerning torus fields.

Comment: @Triatticus will do! thanks :)